# Pass the result of a query to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following scenario:

I have query stored to a variable and what I want is to pass the result of the query to another variable but it is seems that I'm missing something because I'm getting an error.

**Code:**

```
SET @sqlCommand= 'SELECT [COLUMN_NAME] FROM [dbo].[Keys] WHERE [CONSTRAINT_TYPE]=''PRIMARY KEY'' AND [TABLE_NAME]='''+ @Table_Name + ''''

SET @Primary_Key_Name= EXECUTE (@sqlCommand)
```

The error occurred in the the second query where I'm passing the result of the query in the variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using "dynamic" SQL here at all? It doesn't need to be.

Comment: i m using a dynamic SQL because the table name is a variable

Comment: Can you show us the exact error?

Comment: *"i m using a dynamic SQL because the table name is a variable"* That doesn't doesn't explain why you are using dynamic SQL; the table name is a parameter here, not dynamic.

Comment: Good you point! you are right, may thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the query to be a dynamic query here, it can just be properly parametrised:

```sql
SET @Primary_Key_Name = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                         FROM dbo.Keys
                         WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                           AND TABLE_NAME = @Table_Name);
```

If the query can return multiple rows, then use a table type variable instead, and `INSERT` the data into it:

```sql
INSERT INTO @Primary_Key_Names (COLUMN_NAME)
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM dbo.Keys
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
  AND TABLE_NAME = @Table_Name;
```